# Puppet client not pulling changes automatically

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I have a computer that has the puppet client configured, enabled, and running, but it's not pulling changes from the master on its own. If I do a `puppet agent -t` it pulls the changes just fine. Which logs should I check to find out why it's not pulling on its own?

Comment: Puppet's logs would be a good start.

Comment: I have logs on the puppet master disabled, are there any logs on the puppet client machine that will have useful information?

Comment: Yes, if it's running.  If you're having a problem with the client, the client logs is the first place you should look.

Comment: The agent usually logs to syslog by default, so check `/var/log/{messages,syslog}` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard answering your question, since you didn't specify the puppet version number you are using.
Since you are able to run the puppet agent manually, it seems like this is not a puppet.conf or firewall issue.
Please try the following -

1. make sure that the puppet agent is enabled -
   `puppet --enable`
2. edit /etc/default/puppet, make sure that START is set to yes -
   START=yes
3. make sure that the puppet agent daemon is running -
   `/etc/init.d/puppet restart`
4. check the logs on your system, the relevant files should be -
   /var/log/syslog
   /var/log/puppet/puppet.log

Comment: Also, make sure you restart the daemon after changes to puppet.conf

Comment: @ AWippler changing to restart instead of start, as you've suggested.
thanks!